# Can I use a variable in the criteria portion of my Countif formula?

Tags: excel, variables, criteria, countif

First I used the formula:
`=COUNTIF('Reach_ins'!$C$4:$C$43,B18)`  and this outputs the correct number of cells in range C4:C43 that equals the number in cell B18.  This formula works if I change the number in B18.

This formula also works:

```
=COUNTIF('Reach-ins'!$C$4:$C$43,">=15")
```

However, this formula does not work:
`=COUNTIF('Reach-ins'!$C$4:$C$43,">=$B$18")`  where the value in B18 is 15.

I'm trying to pick out the number of cells in range C4:C43 that are >= the vvalue in cell B18 where B18 is a value input by the user.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the cell with `&`:

```
=COUNTIF('Reach-ins'!$C$4:$C$43,">="&$B$18)
```